# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 issue while retrieving NSDATA to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsdata, nsjsonserialization

I am creating iOS app which uses SQLite DB.
I have created Table As:

```
const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ORDERTABLE (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ITEMDESC BLOB)";
```

and then I have to insert self.selectedItemsDictnory Dictionary into ItemDESC
i am inserting as :

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.selectedItemsDictnory options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ORDERTABLE(ITEMDESC)VALUES( \"%@\");",data];
```

Upto this it is successfully done.

Now i have to retrieve this dictionary in same format

what i am doing is :

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(orderDB, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

        const void *blob = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1);
        NSInteger bytes = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:blob length:bytes];
        NSError *error;

        NSMutableString *jsonObject=[NSJSONSerialization
                                         JSONObjectWithData:data
                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                         error:&error];
        NSLog(@"jsonObject is %@ with error %@",jsonObject, error);

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(orderDB);
}
```

And I am getting Error as

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.)

Comment: and my NSDictionary which i am inserting is as
example :

po self.selectedItemsDictnory

$1 = 0x07184170 {
    Light = 50;
    Pasta = 220;
}

I tried to search this error. i found that my JSON which i am retrieving is actually not in a JSON format.
Please provide your Inputs thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not formatting the JSON property. In this:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:self.selectedItemsDictnory options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
```

Now you have a data blob, not a string, but below, you treat it as a string:

```
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ORDERTABLE(ITEMDESC)VALUES( \"%@\");",data];
```

If you want a string:

```
NSString *jsonString = [NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ORDERTABLE(ITEMDESC)VALUES( \"%@\");",jsonString];
```