# iOS Json Serialization Error - NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840

Tags: php, ios, json, serialization

i have a php service that return a json object but when i serialize it from iOS application i get this error

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)"

I have converted the NSData to string and check if it is well formed.

What is the metter?

This is the json serialization

```
json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

and this is the NSData

```
[{"codice":1,"messaggio":"ghplqp6glm7qom52qipojc9q05","output":{"ID_UTENTE":"624","GIORNATA_ATTIVA":{"NUMERO":"7","DESCRIZIONE":"Finale","INIZIO_PRIMA_PARTITA":"2014-07-31 22:00:00","ABILITA_CALCOLO":"1","IN_CORSO":"1"},"IMGSQUADRE":[{"SQUADRA":"ROMA","IMG":"roma.png"},{"SQUADRA":"SAMPDORIA","IMG":"sampdoria.png"},{"SQUADRA":"UDINESE","IMG":"udinese.png"},{"SQUADRA":"CATANIA","IMG":"catania.png"},{"SQUADRA":"GENOA","IMG":"genoa.png"},{"SQUADRA":"PARMA","IMG":"parma.png"},{"SQUADRA":"TORINO","IMG":"torino.png"},{"SQUADRA":"LIVORNO","IMG":"livorno.png"},{"SQUADRA":"CHIEVO","IMG":"chievo.png"},{"SQUADRA":"MILAN","IMG":"milan.png"},{"SQUADRA":"VERONA HELLAS","IMG":"verona hellas.png"},{"SQUADRA":"FIORENTINA","IMG":"fiorentina.png"},{"SQUADRA":"JUVENTUS","IMG":"juventus.png"},{"SQUADRA":"NAPOLI","IMG":"napoli.png"},{"SQUADRA":"BOLOGNA","IMG":"bologna.png"},{"SQUADRA":"ATALANTA","IMG":"atalanta.png"},{"SQUADRA":"LAZIO","IMG":"lazio.png"},{"SQUADRA":"SASSUOLO","IMG":"sassuolo.png"},{"SQUADRA":"INTER","IMG":"inter.png"},{"SQUADRA":"CAGLIARI","IMG":"cagliari.png"},{"SQUADRA":"ALGERIA","IMG":"ALG.png"},{"SQUADRA":"ARGENTINA","IMG":"ARG.png"},{"SQUADRA":"AUSTRALIA","IMG":"AUS.png"},{"SQUADRA":"BELGIO","IMG":"BEL.png"},{"SQUADRA":"BOSNIA","IMG":"BIH.png"},{"SQUADRA":"BRASILE","IMG":"BRA.png"},{"SQUADRA":"CAMERUN","IMG":"CMR.png"},{"SQUADRA":"CILE","IMG":"CHI.png"},{"SQUADRA":"COLOMBIA","IMG":"COL.png"},{"SQUADRA":"COREA DEL SUD","IMG":"KOR.png"},{"SQUADRA":"COSTA D'AVORIO","IMG":"CIV.png"},{"SQUADRA":"COSTARICA","IMG":"CRC.png"},{"SQUADRA":"CROAZIA","IMG":"CRO.png"},{"SQUADRA":"ECUADOR","IMG":"ECU.png"},{"SQUADRA":"FRANCIA","IMG":"FRA.png"},{"SQUADRA":"GERMANIA","IMG":"GER.png"},{"SQUADRA":"GHANA","IMG":"GHA.png"},{"SQUADRA":"GIAPPONE","IMG":"JPN.png"},{"SQUADRA":"GRECIA","IMG":"GRE.png"},{"SQUADRA":"HONDURAS","IMG":"HON.png"},{"SQUADRA":"INGHILTERRA","IMG":"ENG.png"},{"SQUADRA":"IRAN","IMG":"IRN.png"},{"SQUADRA":"ITALIA","IMG":"ITA.png"},{"SQUADRA":"MESSICO","IMG":"MEX.png"},{"SQUADRA":"NIGERIA","IMG":"NGA.png"},{"SQUADRA":"OLANDA","IMG":"NED.png"},{"SQUADRA":"PORTOGALLO","IMG":"POR.png"},{"SQUADRA":"RUSSIA","IMG":"RUS.png"},{"SQUADRA":"SPAGNA","IMG":"ESPA.png"},{"SQUADRA":"SVIZZERA","IMG":"SUI.png"},{"SQUADRA":"URUGUAY","IMG":"URU.png"},{"SQUADRA":"USA","IMG":"USA.png"}],"INVITI":0,"FANTACALCIO":"Mondiale"}}]
```

Comment: You data logging test code was right beside the call to `NSJSONSerialization`? Is the response UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, the response is UTF-8.

Comment: not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279756/nscocoaerrordomain-code-3840-issue-while-retrieving-nsdata-to-nsdictionary ?